# Eclipse Color Themes not being applied to Groovy strings

Tags: eclipse, grails, syntax, groovy, syntax-highlighting

I'm having an issue with the string values inside of .groovy files (and .gsp within ${}).  They are showing as black when I have a dark background color theme selected.  I know how to change the operator color which I fixed, but I seem to be unable to find where the string elements surrounded by quotes color is configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the latest version of Groovy-Eclipse, try upgrading.

Using Groovy-Eclipse 2.8.0, I can control String color in Preferences -> Groovy -> Editor right along with Bracket color, Operator color, etc.